# repartition a dense matrix in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Dense matrix(100*100) in pyspark, and I want to `repartition` it into ten groups with each containing 10 rows.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib import *
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
dm2 = Matrices.dense(100, 100, RandomRDDs.uniformRDD(sc, 10000).collect())
newRdd = sc.parallelize(dm2.toArray())
rerdd = newRdd.repartition(10)
```

the above code results in `rerdd` containing 100 elements. I want to present this matrix `dm2` as row-wise partitioned blocks (e.g., 10 rows in a partition).

Comment: I tried it using a normal numpy matrix and converted into an RDD and partitioned it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739687/partition-a-matrix-rdd-in-pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't make much sense but you can for example do something like this

```
mat =  Matrices.dense(100, 100, np.arange(10000))

n_par = 10
n_row = 100

rdd = (sc
    .parallelize(
        # Add indices
        enumerate(
            # Extract and reshape values
            mat.values.reshape(n_row, -1)))
    # Partition and sort by row index
    .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(n_par, lambda i: i // n_par))
```

Check number of partitions and rows per partition:

```
rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
## [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

Check if the first row contains desired data:

```
assert np.all(rdd.first()[1] == np.arange(100))
```

Comment: `rdd.getNumPartitions()` returns 100

Comment: Works just fine for me.