# partition a matrix RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm converting a numpy matrix into an RDD with partition size 10.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")        
x = np.matrix(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000), dtype=np.float)
x.shape=(100,100)
rdd = sc.parallelize(x, 10)
```

Here each row in RDD is a matrix object, and I can access it using `rdd.collect()[row_num][0]`. **How can I group ten rows into each partition?**. Earlier I tried using a [Dense matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737566/repartition-a-dense-matrix-in-pyspark/36738279#36738279), I couldn't get proper results.

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote it myself. :). I know it's not efficient, but it solves the problem and might help someone, before a better answer is posted.

```
def group_rows(rdd):
    rdd_collect = rdd.collect()
    count = 0
    key_count = 0
    result = {"0":[],"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"6":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":[]}
    for i in range(100):
        if count < 10:
            temp_value = result[str(key_count)]
            temp_value.append(rdd_collect[i][0])
            result[str(key_count)] = temp_value
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
            key_count += 1
    return result

result = group_rows(e3.rdd)
temp = e3.sc.parallelize(result.items())
sorted(temp.groupByKey().collect())
```